# Is it possible to access a photo's geotag metadata from within the simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, alassetslibrary, geotagging

I've written an app that retrieves a photo's GPS metadata, and it works on my iPhone but doesn't in the simulator.  If I drag a photo containing geotags onto the simulator, it gets placed into the photo library.  Then, my app issues this code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *metadata = [assetRepresentation metadata];
```

and `metadata` contains all sorts of items, but not GPS.  Is there some trick to getting the simulator to recognize GPS metadata?

Alternatively, what I'm trying to do is run the app in the simulator as many different devices to get screenshots for the App Store.  How do you prepare App Store screenshots if your app won't work properly in the simulator?

Comment: i think you've answered your own question. You can simulate a screenshot by using the same photo taken from your device and photoshopping it onto another or photoshopping the dimensions

Comment: Well, I have an iPhone 5. Are you suggesting that I take a screenshot from that and then expand it to iPhone 6 Plus dimensions?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.  I think a better approach would be to get GPS metadata working in the simulator, if that's possible.  Then I can take a legitimate screenshot.  Hopefully someone with first-hand knowledge will weigh in.

Comment: Store your photos on a server (box.com, Dropbox etc) and download them through safari of the simulator

Comment: @soulshined: You're right!! I guess the problem wasn't that geotag metadata isn't available inside the simulator, but that when you copy a photo to the simulator via drag and drop, the geotag is removed for some reason.  Thank you!

Comment: you should post it as answer for future question seekers. I don't care to receive credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears that GPS metadata is removed from photos when you copy them to the simulator via drag and drop.  Once I followed @soulshined's suggestion below (put the photo onto Dropbox and downloaded it from within the simulator) then everything worked perfectly.