# iOS Simulator Add Photo with CLocation information

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, photo, alassetslibrary

I am testing my application using Xcode Simulator version 8.2 (latest).  When a user selects a photo my code extracts the CLocation information using the ALAssetsLibrary.  Specifically the property ALAssetPropertyLocation.

How do I test this?  I know how to add photos to the simulator.  I took a photo with my iPhone and placed it in the simulator's Camera Roll by dragging and dropping the photo onto the simulator.  I also verified before I put the photo in the simulator that it has EXIF location data.

The code looks right but I'm guessing that the metadata for the photo may be stored somewhere else and simply copying the photo onto the simulator will not create the CLocation information.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {

         // We'll store the info to use in another function later
        self.selectedPhotoInfo = info;

    // Get picked image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        // Get the asset url
        NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

        // We need to use blocks. This block will handle the ALAsset that's returned:
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            // Get the location property from the asset
            CLLocation *location = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];

            // call image location handler
            [self handleImageLocation:location];
        };
        // This block will handle errors:
        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
            // Do something to handle the error
        };

        // Use the url to get the asset from ALAssetsLibrary,
        // the blocks that we just created will handle results
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:url
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];
      }
```

Comment: how about posting some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get CLLocation by pass your 'myasset' to this method.

```
- (CLLocation *)getLocationOfImageAsset:(ALAsset *)imageAsset {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
    if ([metadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"]) {
        return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[metadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[[metadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suttikeat for your suggestion.  While I can walk the metadata in the debugger I don't see the GPS information in my image.

My original question is how to add an image to the Xcode simulator that has Location information so that I can test this.

To repeat, the image that I am testing with came from an iPhone with Location turned on, I verified in PhotoShop that it had GPS metadata.  It appears that when I bring the image into Xcode Similator the GPS data is no longer in the image.

Comment: I never test it in simulator but you should try to add photo to simulator by another way like upload and download it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129746/is-it-possible-to-access-a-photos-geotag-metadata-from-within-the-simulator?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of Xcode, when a photo is added to the Photo Library in the iOS Simulator, it is converted to a UIImage and placed in the photo library with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum().  This just places the image data in the library and does not preserve EXIF data.

Newer versions (Xcode 7+, I believe) import photos with newer APIs that are able to preserve the EXIF data.